# Checksum Validation after migration from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, oracle11g, checksum, data-migration

I am migrating a large database from oracle 11g to SQL SERVER 2008R2 using SSIS. How can the data integrity can be validated for numeric data using checksum?

Comment: Is there any other way too check the data integrity?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information as to what types of data corruption you suspect might happen?

Comment: Since large number of records spanning over a few GB's are to be transferred there may be potential loss over the data conversions across the platforms. I was looking for way to validate the data in source and destination.

Comment: So you need to verify the data both horizontally (ie, ensure data in every column is correct) and vertically (ensure that no rows are missing, no extra rows are added)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've always done this using a few application controls. It should be something that is easy to compute on both platforms.

Frequently, the end result is a query like:

```
select count(*)
,      count(distinct col1) col1_dist_cnt
...
,      count(distinct col99) col99_dist_cnt
,      sum(col1) col1_sum
...
,      sum(col99) col99_sum
from   table
```

Spool to file, Excel or database and compare outcome. Save for project management and auditors.

Please read more on application control [here](http://www.invantive.com/about-invantive/news/entryid/872/application-controls-for-optimum-system-integrity). I wrote it for checks between various financial reporting systems for the regulatory reporting, so this approach serves most cases.

If exactly one field value is wrong, it will always show up. Two errors might compensate each other. For example row 1 col 1 gets the value from row 2 col 1.

To detect for that, multiply each value with something unique for the row. For instance, if you have a unique ID column or identity that is included in the migration too:

```
,      sum(ID * col1) col1_sum
...
,      sum(ID * col99) col99_sum
```

When you get number overflows, first try using the largest available precision (especially on SQL Server sometimes difficult). If not feasibly anymore, use mod function. Only few types of error are hidden by mod.

Icing on the cake is to auto generate these statements. On Oracle look at user_tables, user_tab_columns. On SQL Server look at syscolumns etc.

Comment: That is an interesting way. Although I took help of some external tools long ago I like this one better. Thanks for the insight!